# Is there a way we could do a poll to determine the mix of disciplines we have here?

Tags: discussion

It would be interesting to know the mix of scientific backgrounds present in this group. Materials modeling has a really broad range of application from very directly correlated to materials and chemistry (quantum chemists and materials scientists), to the more theoretical side where the simulations don't have units (condensed matter physics).

Is there a way to learn that about our new community? I don't know how it would work, but I'm new to SE in general.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to create a poll at one of the usual poll websites and link it here.

Comment: Here in the meta I assume?

Comment: Except for external tools, which may or may not be more engaging (or may or may not be persistent), Meta is probably the best place to start; in fact this post can be it already. If the community is engaged in this, someone of the respective field could leave an answer, others of the same field could upvote this answer, and/or leave a comment. I would probably rephrase the question in that way. A moderator (or in our case a CM) could [meta-tag:feature] it so that it gets more visibility. I think this would be the best way to reach out to the community.